How do I verify if form buttons are disabled when pressing the submit button in Playwright
I have a bit of code that would disable a form when I start the submit process.  This is an classic web app not a Single Page app so the submit button will actually navigate out of the page.  The following is an example HTML of how I implemented this.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>MVCE</title>
  <script>
    function disableForm(theForm) {
      theForm.querySelectorAll("input, textarea, select").forEach(
        /** @param {HTMLInputElement} element */
        (element) => {
          element.readOnly = true;
        }
      );
      theForm
        .querySelectorAll("input[type='submit'], input[type='button'], button")
        .forEach(
          /** @param {HTMLButtonElement} element */
          (element) => {
            element.disabled = true;
          }
        );
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
      function applyDisableFormOnSubmit(formId) {
        document.querySelectorAll("form").forEach((aForm) => {
          aForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            disableForm(aForm);
            aForm.submit();
          });
        });
      });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="generated-form" id="x" method="POST" action="https://httpbun.com/mix/s=200/d=3/b64=dGVzdA==">
    <fieldset>
      <legend> Student:: </legend>
      <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br>
      <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="youremail@gmail.com"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>

I wanted to test the above code is functioning correctly in Playwright, but I cannot get the isDisabled assertion to work in the following code if I uncomment the assertion.
test("disable form", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("http://localhost:8080/");
  const submitButton = page.locator("input[type='submit']");
  await expect(submitButton).toBeEnabled();
  await submitButton.click();
  // await expect(submitButton).toBeDisabled();
  await expect(page)
    .toHaveURL("https://httpbun.com/mix/s=200/d=3/b64=dGVzdA==");
});

The following have been tried
test("disable form", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("http://localhost:8080/");
  const submitButton = page.locator("input[type='submit']");
  await expect(submitButton).toBeEnabled();
  await Promise.all([
    submitButton.click(),
    expect(submitButton).toBeDisabled()
  ]);
  expect(page).toHaveURL("https://httpbun.com/mix/s=200/d=3/b64=dGVzdA==");
});


This also does not work, the example in the answer provided appears to be working until you actually try to verify the following page.
test("disable form", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("http://localhost:8080/");
  const submitButton = page.locator("input[type='submit']");

  await expect(submitButton).toBeEnabled();
  const nav = page.waitForNavigation({timeout: 5000});
  const disabled = expect(submitButton).toBeDisabled({timeout: 1000});
  await submitButton.click();

  // allow disabled check to pass if the nav happens
  // too fast and the button disabled state doesn't render
  await disabled.catch(() => {});
  await nav;

  expect(page).toHaveURL("https://httpbun.com/mix/s=200/d=3/b64=dGVzdA==");
});

I have also tried to modify the route but it still does not work
  await page.route(
    "https://httpbun.com/mix/s=200/d=3/b64=dGVzdA==",
    async (route, req) => {
      console.log("routing")
      expect(page.url()).toEqual(currentUrl);
      await expect(submitButton).toBeVisible();
      await expect(submitButton).toBeDisabled();
      return route.continue();
    }
  );


Why not just show an overlay with pointer-event: none?

Can you share the complete page and testing code as a [mcve]? You might want to start listening for the disabled condition before clicking, otherwise I assume the form submission is so fast that you don't get a chance to catch it.

I eventually did a round about way due to the DOM disappearing when navigation starts.  What I did was replace the form.submit with a dummy method to ensure it doesn't navigate and then invoke it afterwards.  One thing to note is you cannot set the local variables in the evaluate so you need to apply it as an property on the context.
type HTMLFormElementWithFlags = HTMLFormElement & {
  formSubmitCalled: boolean;
  /**
   * Stores the form.submit function to be called later
   */
  savedSubmit: () => void;
};
/**
 *
 * @param formLocator form locator
 * @returns [ submitTrappedForm, isTrappedFormSubmitCalled ]
 */
const trapFormSubmit = async (
  formLocator: Locator
): Promise<[() => Promise<void>, () => Promise<boolean>]> => {
  await formLocator.evaluate((elem: HTMLFormElementWithFlags) => {
    elem.savedSubmit = elem.submit;
    elem.formSubmitCalled = false;
    elem.submit = () => {
      elem.formSubmitCalled = true;
    };
  });
  return [
    async () =>
      formLocator.evaluate((elem: HTMLFormElementWithFlags) => {
        elem.savedSubmit();
      }),
    async () =>
      formLocator.evaluate(
        (elem: HTMLFormElementWithFlags) => elem.formSubmitCalled
      ),
  ];
};

test("disable form on submit", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.setContent(
    `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>MVCE</title>
  <script>
    function disableForm(theForm) {
      theForm.querySelectorAll("input, textarea, select").forEach(
        /** @param {HTMLInputElement} element */
        (element) => {
          element.readOnly = true;
        }
      );
      theForm
        .querySelectorAll("input[type='submit'], input[type='button'], button")
        .forEach(
          /** @param {HTMLButtonElement} element */
          (element) => {
            element.disabled = true;
          }
        );
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
      function applyDisableFormOnSubmit(formId) {
        document.querySelectorAll("form").forEach((aForm) => {
          aForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
            console.log("form is submitting");
            event.preventDefault();
            disableForm(aForm);
            aForm.submit();
            console.log("submit is called");
          });
        });
      });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="generated-form" id="x" method="POST" action="https://httpbun.com/mix/s=200/d=3/b64=dGVzdA==">
    <fieldset>
      <legend> Student:: </legend>
      <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br>
      <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="youremail@gmail.com"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
`
  );
  const submitButton = page.locator("input[type='submit']");

  await expect(submitButton).toBeEnabled();
  const currentUrl = page.url();

  const form = page.locator("form");

  const [submitTrappedForm, isTrappedFormSubmitCalled] =
    await trapFormSubmit(form);
  await submitButton.click();
  expect(page.url()).toEqual(currentUrl);
  expect(await isTrappedFormSubmitCalled()).toBe(true);
  await expect(submitButton).toBeVisible();
  await expect(submitButton).toBeDisabled();
  await submitTrappedForm();

  await page.waitForURL("https://httpbun.com/mix/s=200/d=3/b64=dGVzdA==");
  await expect(page).toHaveURL(
    "https://httpbun.com/mix/s=200/d=3/b64=dGVzdA=="
  );
  const content = await page.content();
  // Cannot use toEqual because playwright wraps it as an HTML.
  expect(content).toContain("test");
});


At present Playwright does not appear to support this capability as per
per https://playwright.dev/docs/navigations#navigation-events

Navigation starts by changing the page URL or by interacting with the page (e.g., clicking a link). The navigation intent may be canceled, for example, on hitting an unresolved DNS address or transformed into a file download.

Once navigation starts the elements are no longer accessible until the page is loaded even with noWaitAfter: true
Opened this feature request to hopefully solve the issue https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/31596

After OP's update clarifying their use case, it doesn't seem like this is possible currently, because the navigation immediately invalidates elements on the page, making it impossible to find them or assert on their state.
I'll leave my original answer below for context.

Assuming the submission is fast, I'd try listening for the disabled condition first, then clicking, so you won't miss the brief state that occurs only for an instant before page refresh:
const submitButton = page.locator("#SubmitButton")
await expect(submitButton).toBeEnabled();
await Promise.all([
  expect(submitButton).toBeDisabled(),
  submitButton.click(),
]);

If the page refresh happens instantly, the assertion will fail because the page refresh caused by the .submit() call will occur before the page gets a chance to render the disabled form state. Assuming it pertains accurately enough to your use case, you can play with the following example to see the behavior:
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.42.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<form><input id="SubmitButton" type="submit"></form>
<script>
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const disableFormFields = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
   form
    .querySelectorAll("input, textarea, select")
    .forEach((element) => {
      element.readOnly = true;
    });
  form
    .querySelectorAll("input[type='submit'], input[type='button'], button")
    .forEach((element) => {
      element.disabled = true;
    });

  // Added for experimentation purposes, feel free to adjust or remove
  setTimeout(() => form.submit(), 100);
};
form.addEventListener("submit", disableFormFields);
</script></body></html>`;

test("button is disabled during submit", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  const submitButton = page.locator("#SubmitButton");
  await expect(submitButton).toBeEnabled();
  await Promise.all([
    expect(submitButton).toBeDisabled(),
    submitButton.click(),
  ]);
});

So if the submission is fast, you may not be able to accurately test this, short of instrumenting the source page a bit.
An alternative idea is to make the expect(submitButton).toBeDisabled() race against a navigation expectation. If the nav expectation runs first and the disabled check never gets a chance to run, then consider that test a pass too.
Something like:
test("button is disabled during submit", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  const submitButton = page.locator("#SubmitButton");
  await expect(submitButton).toBeEnabled();
  const nav = page.waitForNavigation({timeout: 5000});
  const disabled = expect(submitButton).toBeDisabled({timeout: 1000});
  await submitButton.click();

  // allow disabled check to pass if the nav happens
  // too fast and the button disabled state doesn't render
  await disabled.catch(() => {});
  await nav;
});

One downside of this approach is that if the nav beats the disabled state, which it would under normal circumstances without the timeout, then your test will incur the 1 second penalty. Not terrible, but a bit slower than it should be. You can lower the timeout at the risk of false positives.
If this doesn't work, please share a complete, reproducible example with the page under test so I can see the issue first hand and experiment.

I can't seem to get it to work.

Can you elaborate on that? What isn't working exactly? My example works; can you provide a failing example of an actual page so we both have shared context?

I added the xample above but I can't get the "disabled" to fire.  The hard part is getting a backend service that's testable that would do a delay.

your second example doesn't check the resulting output so while it does check for "disabled" the post navigation does not pass.

setTimeout(() => form.submit(), 100); simulates a slow backend. Adjust accordingly. Your expect(page).toHaveURL("https://httpbun.com/mix/s=200/d=3/b64=dGVzdA=="); is missing an await.

That said, I'm seeing await expect(submitButton).toBeDisabled(); failing, probably because once the navigation begins, the page immediately drops its previous context even though it still shows on the screen. So yeah, I'm not sure how to test this, but I'll look into this more if I get a chance.

I came to the same conclusion.  Then open this https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/31596
